# same pattern on two tables [R]

Tags: r, dataframe, concatenation

I have 2 data frames and I need to create one

let me explain:

My two tables contain a lot of lines: here is an exemple:

```
V1   V2         V3          V4    V5     V6   V7
1 A Complete  scaffold_544  98748 122355 4337.2 2808
2 B Complete scaffold_1077  32765  40727 2934.3 1759
3 C Complete    scaffold_2  65354  76523 3248.4 1924
4 D Complete  scaffold_174  33084  44463 1403.8 1171

  V1   V2         V3          V4    V5     V6   V7
1 A Complete  scaffold_544  98748 122355 4337.2 2808
2 E Complete scaffold_1077  32765  40727 2934.3 1759
3 G Complete    scaffold_2  65354  76523 3248.4 1924
4 D Complete  scaffold_174  33084  44463 1403.8 1171
```

and then I need to compare the V1 column and creat a table such this one:

```
  seq_paired_names   
1 A 
2 D
```

Thanks you very much.

Answer (score 1):

If you want values of `V1` for which the corresponding rows are equal between the two tables, you can do an `inner_join` as below.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  inner_join(df2) %>% 
  select(seq_paired_names = V1)
```

If you just want to know which values of `V1` are in both tables, you can use `intersect`.

```
data.frame(seq_paired_names = intersect(df1$V1, df2$V1))
```

Data Used

```
df1 <- read.table(text = 'V1   V2         V3          V4    V5     V6   V7
1 A Complete  scaffold_544  98748 122355 4337.2 2808
                  2 B Complete scaffold_1077  32765  40727 2934.3 1759
                  3 C Complete    scaffold_2  65354  76523 3248.4 1924
                  4 D Complete  scaffold_174  33084  44463 1403.8 1171'
                  ,head = T
                  ,stringsAsFactors = F)
df2 <- read.table(text = '  V1   V2         V3          V4    V5     V6   V7
1 A Complete  scaffold_544  98748 122355 4337.2 2808
                  2 E Complete scaffold_1077  32765  40727 2934.3 1759
                  3 G Complete    scaffold_2  65354  76523 3248.4 1924
                  4 D Complete  scaffold_174  33084  44463 1403.8 1171'
                  ,head = T
                  ,stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple base R solution:

```
data.frame(seq_paired_names = df1$V1[df1$V1 %in% df2$V1])
```